# Custom swiper not working for body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a custom swiper with alerts. Its code is in this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/w2KZVNyhQYepqsb7xmiV?p=preview).
When I swipe from left to right or right to left, it gives alerts successfully.
Here, I've used only div for swiping action. Code is like this:

```
<div id="test" class="text-center"></div>  

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $(".text-center").swiperight(function() {  
                /*$("#myCarousel").carousel('prev');  */
                alert("Swiped to right");
            });  
            $(".text-center").swipeleft(function() {  
                /*$("#myCarousel").carousel('next');  */
                alert("Swiped to left");
            });  
        });  
</script>
```

If I change the id for body like this,

```
<style type="text/css">
    #test{
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #0067ac;
        width:100%;
        height:500px;
    }
    .text-center{
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 3%;
        margin-top: 5%;
    }    
<body id="test" class="text-center">
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $("#test").swiperight(function() {  
                /*$("#myCarousel").carousel('prev');  */
                alert("Swiped to right");
            });  
            $("#test").swipeleft(function() {  
                /*$("#myCarousel").carousel('next');  */
                alert("Swiped to left");
            });  
        });  
    </script>
```

Then swiping works. [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/qM5535Ty2fLbzC21JsgV?p=preview) is here.
But if I apply it to my code, then it doesn't work for the `body` tag . My code is:

```
<div id = "mainDiv" class = "container" style="padding:0px;width:100%;height:100%">
            <div id = "header">
                <span id = "icons">
                    <span id = "menu"></span>
                    <span onclick="goBack()" id = "back"></span>
                </span>
                <span id = "title">
                    <span id="junos"> JUNOS </span><span id = "genius">GENIUS</span> 
                </span>
            </div>

            <div id ="body" class="container-fluid" style="position:relative;">
            <!-- <div id="swiper"> -->
                  <div id="searchMenu" class="col-xs-4" style="height:400px; overflow-y:auto;padding:0px;display:none;min-width: 250px;background-color:transparent;">
            </div>
                <p class="text-center" onclick="goBack()"  style="padding-top:12px;">Help</p>
                 <!-- Start  -->
                     <ul class="list=unstyled text-justify" style="margin-right:20px;">
<li> JUNOS GENIUS is a fun way to improve your skills with Juniper Networks Junos operating system and prepare for technical certification. The Application is a virtual flashcard reader that includes decks of multiple choice questions for several Junos-based exams including JNCIA-Junos, JNCIS-ENT, JNCIS-SEC, and JNCIS-SP. You answer multiple-choice questions and get immediate feedback on accuracy of the answer. </li>
<li> Questions may be answered in Study Mode, Timed Test Mode, or Challenge Instructor Mode. </li>

<ul>

<li> In Study Mode, choose the question category that interests you and begin answering questions. The system will not track your score and no achievements are earned for correct answers.  </li>
<li> To enter Timed Test Mode, choose any question category and then tap Timed Test. This will simulate a live exam and provide you with 60 minutes to answer 60 questions selected at random from among all categories in the deck. You will see percentage correct score on completion of 60 questions or at the end of 60 minutes (whichever comes first). </li>
<li>
To enter Challenge Instructor Mode, choose a question category then tap Challenge Instructor to challenge the ranks of instructors. Score higher on the category than the instructor to earn a device achievement. Device achievements are specific to question category. Instructors should be challenged, and beaten, repeatedly to earn higher quantities of device achievements for use in your ‘My Network’. Beating instructors becomes progressively more difficult as you work through the ranks.
</li>
</ul>
<li>My Network:
Device achievements (earned by beating instructors in Challenge Instructor Mode) are used to build network views in a handy network drawing tool called My Network. All Juniper Networks devices earned are available for addition to the My Network view. You are also able to add LAN segments, WAN segments, and end user devices including laptops, printers, and servers to the My Network view. And you have the ability to share your My Network diagram through email or social media.</li>

</ul>
                 <!-- End   -->
                </div>
            </div>  
#mainDiv {
            background-image: url("../JunosImages/mob/junos_genius_P_960x720_question_blank_phone.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
/*custom js*/
          $(document).ready(function() {  
            $("#mainDiv").swiperight(function() {  
              alert("Swiped to right");
            });  
            $("#mainDiv").swipeleft(function() {  
              alert("Swiped to left");
            });  
          });
```

Comment: did you properly linked jquery mobile?

Comment: Yeah, I've properly linked `jquery mobile`. Check that `plunkr`

Comment: Works fine **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bi7PSJ7S12XfHlPjgUml?p=preview)**

Comment: you need to provide a width to the body tag

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/5d4tWZ1DESkya7YhACwE?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem with your css.

I just updated the css and it worked fine :

Check out this fiddle [plunker Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/qM5535Ty2fLbzC21JsgV?p=preview)

Css Updations are here:

```
<style type="text/css">
#test{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0067ac;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
}
.text-center{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @AjayKulkarni Where is your body tag in your original code ?

Comment: I've used `<div id="body"></div>`

Comment: @AjayKulkarni Position , width and height may effect this code. Try changing them.

Comment: Yeah, I changed `height` and `width`. It is working now. Thank you :)